# React How to get props from parent props in react-select Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-bootstrap, react-select

i have problem with react-select, when i want to get a value from the props of parent element in react select

```
import React from 'react'
import Select,{ components } from 'react-select'
import { FormLabel } from 'react-bootstrap'

const componentSelect = ({errors,...props}) => {
    console.log(props) // return props of react-select component
    console.log(errors) // this line return undefined

    return (<div>
      <components.Control {...props} />
      <div className="invalid-feedback">Error {errors?.message}</div>
    </div>)
};
```

and the react-select component like this:

```
export const StandardSelect = ({
    options=[],
    label,
    key,
    errors,
    ...props
})=>{
    return (
        <div className="form-group mb-3 " {...key || ''}>
            <FormLabel>{label}</FormLabel>
            <Select components={errors && {Control:componentSelect}} options={options}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

how can i get the `errors` props from this :

```
export const StandardSelect = ({
    options=[],
    label,
    key,
    errors, //==>> this props <<==
    ...props
})=>{
```

into this component:

```
const componentSelect = ({errors,...props}) => {
    console.log(props) // return props of react-select component
    console.log(errors) // ==>> into this line expect return `errors` from `StandardSelect`<<===

    return (<div>
      <components.Control {...props} />
      <div className="invalid-feedback">Error {errors?.message}</div>
    </div>)
};
```

did you have any idea or solutions?

i'm so glad if you had :)

NB: for the good documentation the react-select, so `componentSelect` declared in the outside of `StandardSelect` scope. looks this docs [react-select components defining](https://react-select.com/components#defining-components)

*sorry for my bad english :)